# Python/BeautifulSoup - Getting specific attribute in the same tag/element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and BeautifulSoup. So please forgive me if I'm using the wrong terminology.

I am trying to get a specific 'text' from a div tag/element that has multiple attributes in the same .

```
<div class="property-item" data-id="183" data-name="Brittany Apartments" data-street_number="240" data-street_name="Brittany Drive" data-city="Ottawa" data-province="Ontario" data-postal="K1K 0R7" data-country="Canada" data-phone="613-688-2222" data-path="/apartments-for-rent/brittany-apartments-240-brittany-drive-ottawa/" data-type="High-rise-apartment" data-latitude="45.4461070" data-longitude="-75.6465360" >
```

Below is my code to loop through and find 'property-item'

```
for btnMoreDetails in citySoup.findAll(attrs= {"class":"property-item"}):
```

My question is, if I specifically want the 'data-name' and 'data-path' for example, how do I go about getting it?

I've searched google and even this website. Some were saying using the .contents[2]. But I still wasn't able to get any of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have extracted the element (which `findAll` does one at a time) you can access attributes as though they were dictionary keys. So for example the following code:

```
data = """<div class="property-item" data-id="183" data-name="Brittany Apartments" data-street_number="240" data-street_name="Brittany Drive" data-city="Ottawa" data-province="Ontario" data-postal="K1K 0R7" data-country="Canada" data-phone="613-688-2222" data-path="/apartments-for-rent/brittany-apartments-240-brittany-drive-ottawa/" data-type="High-rise-apartment" data-latitude="45.4461070" data-longitude="-75.6465360" >"""

import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)
for btnMoreDetails in soup.findAll(attrs= {"class":"property-item"}):
    print btnMoreDetails["data-name"]
```

prints out

```
Brittany Apartments
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved and reps up to you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the `data-name` and `data-path` attributes, you can simply use the *dictionary-like access* to `Tag`'s attributes:

```
for btnMoreDetails in citySoup.findAll(attrs={"class":"property-item"}):
    print(btnMoreDetails["data-name"])
    print(btnMoreDetails["data-path"])
```

Note that you can also use the [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to match the property items:

```
for property_item in citySoup.select(".property-item"):
    print(property_item["data-name"])
    print(property_item["data-path"])
```

FYI, if you want to see *all the attributes* use [`.attrs` property](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
for property_item in citySoup.select(".property-item"):
    print(property_item.attrs)
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved and reps up to you.